# How to pass controller toggle to other file?

Tags: flutter

I want to pass my controller toggle (which is on my example custom menu script) to another file so it will open and close my sliding menu.

For instance:

The first script is my ExampleCustomMenu with the controller toggle and the second (which is part of the script) is without.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Main Controllers/My Recipes/My Recipes.dart';
import 'hidden_drawer_menu.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Main Controllers/Settings+Acount/Settings.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Main Controllers/GroceryList/GroceryList.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Main Controllers/Pantry/Pantry.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Main Controllers/Meal Plan/MealPlan.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Main Controllers/Recipets/Recipets.dart';

class ExampleCustomMenu extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SimpleHiddenDrawer(

     menu: Menu(),

     screenSelectedBuilder: (position, controller) {
       Widget screenCurrent;
       switch (position) {
         case 0:
           screenCurrent = Settings();
           break;
         case 1:
           screenCurrent = MyRecipes();
           break;
         case 2:
           screenCurrent = GroceryList();
           break;
         case 3:
           screenCurrent = Pantry();
           break;
         case 4:
           screenCurrent = MealPlan();
           break;
         case 5:
           screenCurrent = Recipets();
           break;
       }

       return Scaffold(
         //appBar: AppBar(
           //title: Text("Look at this "),

           //leading: IconButton(
            //   icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              // onPressed: () {
               //  controller.toggle();
              // }),
         //),

         backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF1744),
         body: screenCurrent,
       );
     },
   );

 }


}

class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 AnimationController _animationController;
 bool initConfigState = false;

 @override
 void initState() {
   _animationController =
       AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100));
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   confListenerState(context);

   return Container(
     width: double.maxFinite,
     height: double.maxFinite,
     color: Colors.blue,
     child: Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
         Container(
           width: double.maxFinite,
           height: double.maxFinite,
         ),
         FadeTransition(
           opacity: _animationController,
           child: Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
             child: Align(
               alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
               child: Column(
                 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 200.0,
                     height: 150,
                     child: RaisedButton(
                       color: Colors.white,
                       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                           borderRadius:
                               BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                       onPressed: () {
                         SimpleHiddenDrawerProvider.of(context)
                             .setSelectedMenuPosition(0);
                       },
                       child: Text(
                         "Settings",
                         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 200.0,
                     child: RaisedButton(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                         onPressed: () {
                           SimpleHiddenDrawerProvider.of(context)
                               .setSelectedMenuPosition(1);
                         },
                         child: Text(
                           "My Recipes",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                         )),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 200.0,
                     child: RaisedButton(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                         onPressed: () {
                           SimpleHiddenDrawerProvider.of(context)
                               .setSelectedMenuPosition(2);
                         },
                         child: Text(
                           "Grocery List",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                         )),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 200.0,
                     child: RaisedButton(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                         onPressed: () {
                           SimpleHiddenDrawerProvider.of(context)
                               .setSelectedMenuPosition(3);
                         },
                         child: Text(
                           "Pantry",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                         )),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 200.0,
                     child: RaisedButton(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                         onPressed: () {
                           SimpleHiddenDrawerProvider.of(context)
                               .setSelectedMenuPosition(4);
                         },
                         child: Text(
                           "Meal Plan",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                         )),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 200.0,
                     child: RaisedButton(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                             borderRadius:
                                 BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                         onPressed: () {
                           SimpleHiddenDrawerProvider.of(context)
                               .setSelectedMenuPosition(5);
                         },
                         child: Text(
                           "Recipets",
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                         )),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }

 void confListenerState(BuildContext context) {
   if (!initConfigState) {
     initConfigState = true;
     SimpleHiddenDrawerProvider.of(context)
         .getMenuStateListener()
         .listen((state) {
       if (state == MenuState.open) {
         _animationController.forward();
       }

       if (state == MenuState.closing) {
         _animationController.reverse();
       }
     });
   }
 }
}
```

Second Script:

```
import 'package:mykitchen/Backend/SlideOutMenu/ExampleCustomMenu.dart';
import 'Account.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Backend/AnimtedButton/AnimatedButton.dart';
import 'package:mykitchen/Sliverappbartry.dart';

const PrimaryColor = const Color(0xFFFFFFFF);

class Settings extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Hello there'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);
}
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
final String title;
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => 
                       Navigator.pop(context),
                        //controller.toggle();
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/UI/menu.png')),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          expandedHeight: 145.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          //floating: true,
          pinned: true,
          elevation: 0.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[

                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Settings',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 22.0),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            background: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[

                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 32, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Change Settings',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          fontSize: 16.0),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

So instead of Navigator.pop(context) it would be controller.toggle for the second script, how do I make this work?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Homepage like:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title,@required this. toggleFunction}) : super(key: key);
final String title;
final void Function toggleFunction
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                        widget.toggleFunction();
                    } 
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/UI/menu.png')),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          expandedHeight: 145.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          //floating: true,
          pinned: true,
          elevation: 0.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[

                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Settings',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 22.0),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            background: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[

                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 32, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Change Settings',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          fontSize: 16.0),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Since I could not find where you are calling homepage,so wherever you are calling MyHomePage pass the function over there like:

```
child: MyHomePage(
title:"title",
toggleFunction:(){
controller.toggle();
}
),
```

Comment: Hi Harpreet, I kind of understand what you are saying, I am struggling with context (as in where does these go in my code? Thanks (sorry just started using dart)

Comment: @StefanFletcher Please share the full code for both the screens for reference.

Comment: I update the code above, unfortunatly I can't add more code to the second due to it being over the limit, essentially that is the most important part and then after that there is just some sliverpadding with curley braces to round it off. Thanks